# ui-router: trying to reload page with no params

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I'm encountering a reload problem with ui-router.

My navbar links to a submitForm page:

```
<a ui-sref=".submitForm">
```

submitForm can also take parameters, if someone is trying to edit a previously created form.  The navbar should always link to a no parameters version.

However, if I'm on a version with parameters, then the navbar just reloads the page with the same parameters.

Any idea why or how I can fix this? Thanks!

Comment: could you post a js fiddle?

Comment: can call `$state.reload()`